# Dynamic scrollbar on hover causing jumping effect on content

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is there a way to avoid the jumping up/down effect caused when the scrollbar is added on hover in this scenario? I understand it's taking the space of the scrollbar area but looking to avoid it with some clever use of positioning or padding or something and so far been unsuccessful. To recreate, see example below, scroll to the bottom of the section and mouse out & in to see the jumping up and down of the content inside it.

```css
section {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}

nav {
  border: red 1px dashed;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Mouse in / out</li>
      <li>Watch me jump up / down</li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Other than adding space for the scroll bar, I don't believe so.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried that, once you scroll back down it just starts jumping again :D

Comment: @Pete it's what was asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some padding equal to the size of scrollbars on the right and bottom, then remove it on hover:

```css
section {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav {
  border: red 1px dashed;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

section:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}

section:hover ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Scroll to bottom</li>
      <li>Mouse in / out</li>
      <li>Watch me jump up / down</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Let me play with this, that's the kind of answer I should have figured in the first place, will just have to be foregiving on the padding since the scrollbar sizes aren't consistent between browsers. +1 so far though.

Comment: I think firefox, ie and chrome all have the rail at 20px.  Not sure about safari though, they like to be all arty farty

Comment: You could use something like we do - we use this plugin: https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html so the scrollbar only appears on hover - see the mac osx demo (and you can style it how you want).  That way it is always scrollable, but you only see the bars on hover and you won't have any troubles with jumping

Comment: Ya this causes some unexpected behavior between parent / children in the various browsers so I'll have to tinker with it some more. However we're trying to eliminate jquery overall and personally I don't think it worth throwing in additional measuring of panels to find scrollbar sizes etc just for when a user happens to be at the very bottom of the panel that just happens to have horizontal scroll (won't even be noticed 99% of time imo) so might look into punting it for now :D

Comment: This more or less works with some javascript to handle identifying size variances in the panels vs scrollbar sizes in various browsers. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try hiding the scrollbar, or blend it in the background. When the parent container is hovered, you can then simply add a background color to pop it up.

Example code below:

HTML (index.html):

```
<ul>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
<li>test<li>
</ul>
```

SCSS / SASS (style.scss):

```
ul {
   height: 100px; // set limit height
   overflow: auto; // creates scroll
      &::-webkit-scrollbar {
          width: 10px; // this basically the width of the scroll bar
      }

      &:hover { // activate if "<ul/>" is hovered
          &::-webkit-scrollbar { // refers to the scrollbar 
              background: white; //  add background
          }
          &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { // refers to the thumb within scrollbar
              background: orange; // add background 
          }
      }
}
```

Result: http://recordit.co/U9LpHMKG9d

Comment: Best and simplest solution. Saved my day. Thanks @Nivek